# How to pass in variable in over clause

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I am trying to pass in a variable into an over clause.

Initially I had it hard coded to something like `over (partition by deviceid order by readdate rows between current row and 2 following)`

Is there a way to do something like 
`over (partition by deviceid order by readdate rows between current row and continuousexcessivehours following)`

or something like 
`over (partition by deviceid order by readdate rows between current row and ISNULL(continuousexcessivehours, 2) following)`

Error I get:  Error: Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "continuousexcessivehours"

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That might depend on the database.  Tag your question with the database you are using.  And, what happens when you try this?

Comment: @GordonLinoff added the db that i'm hitting against. It only occurs when I try to pass in a variable. If I pass in 2, it works fine. Almost like it has to be a static number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some technologies that execute parameterized SQL statements allow parameters at some specific points in the SQL statement **ONLY**.

For example, DB2 does not allow parameters to limit the returned rows: while this parameterized JDBC statement is valid:

```
select * from t where status = ? order by amount fetch first 10 rows only
```

...this one is not:

```
select * from t where status = ? order by amount fetch first ? rows only
```

My guess is you are facing a similar limitation of the engine, or the driver.

The best workaround I've found so far is to *inject* the problematic parameters as a string, concatenating it to the SQL statement. For example, in Java you could do:

```
// parameters

int status = 3;
int maxRows = 10;

// execution

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
  "select * from t where status = ? order by amount fetch first " 
  + maxRows
  + " rows only"
);
ps.setInt(1, status);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Both parameters are used, but in different ways:

1. `status` is included as a traditional JDBC parameter.
2. `maxRows` is injected as a plain String (SQL Injection).

In your case, you can use the second strategy for the parameter `continuousexcessivehours`.

Many ORMs offer solutions to accomplish this. For example MyBatis offers `#{status}` for the first case, and `${maxRows}` for the second one. Did you spot the difference?

Finally, a last word of advice: be careful with SQL injection. Only perform string injection for a parameter if you are sure your know the origin of its value, and it's not coming from an unknown source.

Comment: I had it like this initially, thought there would have been a way to use values from a different table. I'll resort to injection. Thanks